# Backup and Restore Sharepoint Site (NOT Site Collection)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

**My Setup:**
Sharepoint 2010 with SP1
SiteCollection URL: `http://sp2010:8083/`
Site URL: `http://sp2010:8083/abc`

**Requirement:**
Need to change the URL of the Site
from `http://sp2010:8083/abc`
to `http://sp2010:8083/ict`

**My Approach:**
Use Backup-SPSite and Restore-SPSite commands to backup the site **abc** and then restore it on the site **ict**

**Problem:**
Backup-SPSite and Restore-SPSite work for Site collections but are not working for Sites. I get the following error

```
The specified URL is not a top-level Web site. The backup and
restore operations work only for top-level Web sites. Enter the URL for a site
to try the operation again.
```

Kindly help how to change the URL of the site. I am aware of the fact that you cannot change the URL of a Sharepoint site but I think backup and restore can be used to achieve the same.

I am not able to understand that how a company like Microsoft not provide an option to change the URL easily.

Thanks,

Nitin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to use

```
Export-spweb –identity http://sp2010:8083/abc -path c:\sitebkup\mysite.bak

Import-SPWeb –identity http://sp2010:8083/ict -path c:\sitebkup\mysite.bak
```